# From where "Create Controlfile" Command Picks SCN Value while we create Controlfile after we lose all

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Can anyone you put some light on when we create a controlfile in Oracle Database when we lose all using "Create Controlfile" command, from where it picks up the SCN to store in the controlfile and accordingly proceed with the next step that could be recovery or startup the database.

Comment: can you be more clear? Can you describe the scenario you are working on?

Comment: Thanks for reply however I got my answer here - http://avdeo.com/2008/05/29/oracle-database-recovery-details/